# How to control build action of a SQL Server Database Project in VS2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, database-project, sql-server-data-tools

I just upgraded a solution from VS2010 to VS2012 that contained a Database Project.  The upgrade wizard walked me through the steps of converting the project to the new "SQL Server Database Project" format.

Everything works fine, but when I build the solution, this project builds every time, regardless of whether or not anything has changed.  The old Database Project didn't build unless a file had been modified within the project, which is the behavior I would expect from any VS project type.

The database project is large, and this significantly slows development time.  I don't see any settings on the build tab of the project properties that would control this.

I can set up a new solution configuration that doesn't build the database, but is this really my only recourse?  Surely there's a better option.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, and I'm not even sure if this is what you want, but it can have something to do with the "Copy to Output Directory" option. In the old Database Project you had "Copy if newer" and now it changed to "Copy always"...

Cheers!